# amazon ec2 metadata load balanced position

Tags: amazon-ec2

Im just wondering if there is any part of the amazon ec2 meta-data which actually describes a number or position of the ec2 instance within a load balanced list of instances.

As an example, if I was on a particular node and did

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/load-balancer-index
```

the result may be 0,1,2,3 depending on which host I was on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such option. The EC2 instance meta-data contains only the instance specific information (Reservation id, private/public IP/hostname, AMi id, instance id, availability zone...etc). What you are looking for is a ELB related information.